# Why do you have to dereference the label of data to store something in there: Assembly 8086 FASM

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, fasm

Consider the following example:

`mov al, [variable1]`

This makes sense, as you save in the register al the content (thus dereferencing it) of variable1.

Now consider this example:

`mov dword L6, 1`

This isn't correct; the correct form is

`mov dword [L6], 1`

If we're moving 1 to memory, I should tell it to be stored at that address and not at the content. Say you're telling someone to go to a certain place for a party, you'd give them the address of the party and not the people in there.

So, why is this?

Comment: Dereference means you're accessing the content. That is either reading from it or writing  to it. You don't want to write (change) the address, which is not possible, you want to write (change) the content.

Comment: x86 doesn't have memory-indirect data addressing.  It's the difference between 0 and 1 levels of indirection vs. the symbol address as an immediate, not 1 vs. 2

Comment: if I think of mov as write it makes a lot more sense. Can I think of mov as write instead of "moving?

Comment: Yes.  `mov` just copies from the source operand to the destination operand.  That's why the destination has to be pointed-to memory or a register.

Answer (score 2):

x86 doesn't have memory-indirect data addressing.  It's the difference between 0 and 1 levels of indirection vs. the symbol address as an immediate, not 1 vs. 2.

Unlike C, in FASM (and NASM) syntax, mentioning a bare symbol name is the address *as a value*.

e.g. `mov eax, symbol` sets EAX = the address where you put that label, with a `mov eax, imm32` instruction, not a load from memory.

Of course `mov symbol, eax` can't work because an immediate constant can't be a destination, only a `[disp32]` addressing mode.

> if I think of mov as write it makes a lot more sense. Can I think of `mov` as write instead of "moving?

Yes. mov just copies from the source operand to the destination operand. **That's why the destination has to be pointed-to memory or a register.**  But the source operand can be an immediate, register, or memory.

(Of course you can't have both src and dst be memory for a single `mov` instruction; there are [different forms](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) for different kinds of operands.)

---

**An asm symbol in FASM and NASM works kind of like C `char arr[]`.**

You can't do `arr = x;` - the asm equivalent is `mov arr, al` which isn't legal either (in FASM and NASM syntax).

But you can do `*arr = x;` which in asm is `mov [arr], al`

---

**FYI: MASM syntax is different**:  instead of symbols working as a placeholder for a number in all contexts, `mov sym, al` is a store the same as `mov [sym], al` and the brackets are optional and meaningless without a register.

If you see any MASM examples or GCC/clang `.intel_syntax noprefix` output; that's what's going on.