# Is there a way to dereference a pointer stored in memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dereference, addressing-mode

I'm trying to store a pointer in a variable located on memory. How could I dereference it?
I'm trying to do it like this:

```
pointer: db 0 ; the pointer variable
var: db 44 ; the normal variable
dereferenced: db 0 ; the result of dereferencing the value on `pointer`
start:
  mov al, var ; move `var`'s address to `al` register
  mov [pointer], al ; storing the previously moved `var`'s address on `pointer`
  ; dereferencing should go here
```

PS: I'm using `nasm` on Linux

I've already tried `[[pointer]]` but it gives me an error.

PPS: The error is only when trying to dereference.

Comment: Not in one instruction, no; x86 can't do that.  You need to load it into a register.  Also note that pointers are 4 or 8 bytes wide (depending on 32 vs. 64-bit mode).  e.g. `mov ecx, [pointer]` / `mov [ecx], al`

Comment: Forgot to say that it's in 16-bit mode, when you boot the PC.
And, the result of deferencing is actually gonna be stored on `al`.

Comment: PS: also tried to `mov cl, [pointer]` and then `mov al, [cl]`. (and it didn't work)

Comment: `cl` is an 8-bit register, not 16-bit which you'd need for a pointer.  And 16-bit mode has extra restrictions. [Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: \[bx\] works, \[cx\] doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53866854).  And re: brackets, see [Why do you have to dereference the label of data to store something in there: Assembly 8086 FASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61105502) and [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101)

Comment: `mov al, var`. Adresses are 16-bit in real mode. Compiler doesn't protest?

Comment: @Nassau: NASM will take the low 8 bits of the address.  Usually (when making a 32-bit or 64-bit executable) this leads to a link error as the actual address doesn't fit, but when making a flat binary NASM is also the linker.  And depending on the `org` setting (default 0), the absolute address may actually be small.  (Since this deals with the offset part of a seg:off address.)  e.g. if you assembled this source file as-is, `mov al, var` should assemble to `mov al, 1`.  Using 8-bit pointers, you need to load them like `movzx bx, byte [pointer]` to zero-extend to 16-bit.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> pointer: db 0 ; the pointer variable
> ```

`db` is one byte, this means: 8 bits.

You are running a program on an x86. This means that a "normal" pointer is at least 16 bits (if you are running in 16-bit mode) in size.

> I've already tried `[[pointer]]` but it gives me an error.

In assembly language, one instruction corresponds to one instruction that can be executed by the CPU.

In 1959, IBM built a computer that could dereference multiple levels of pointers (you would write this as `[[[pointer]]]`) in one single instruction. However, most modern computers are not able to do this. This is also true for x86-based computers. Such CPUs require multiple instructions to dereference a multi-level pointer:

First, they load the pointer into a register in one instruction; then they use the address in the register in the second instruction.

Example (x86, 32-bit):

```
mov eax, [pointer]
mov ebx, [eax]
```

And because one assembly instruction normally corresponds to exactly one CPU instruction, you also need to do this in assembly language.

Comment: The most recent ISA with double-indirect addressing I know is NS32000.  The famous PDP-11 has it, too.

Comment: The VAX (32-bit follow on of PDP-11) has several *deferred* addressing modes, which do a second memory access.

Comment: Since as you say it's 16-bit code, your example should be more like `mov si, [pointer]` / `mov bl, [si]`.  And you mentioned `pointer: db 0` is wrong, but not what it should be instead: `pointer: dw 0`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I wrote **at least** 16 bits (in the case of 16-bit code). However, I clarify my answer...

Comment: Your example would be more helpful to people writing 16-bit code if loaded the pointer into `ebx`, `esi`, or `edi`, since the 16-bit versions of those register can be dereferenced.  `[ax]` can't. ([Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: \[bx\] works, \[cx\] doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53866854)).  Your example would Just Work by changing both registers to 16-bit if you used EBX instead of EAX for the pointer.